# Javascript Facebook PHP - Send notifications

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, iframe

I want to send out, every monday at 10 am (cronjob) notifications to all my users that are using my app that a new round has begun.

The problem is, it works now for 5-6 testuser, thats fine, but what will happen if the app has more than 1000 user (e.g).
My hosting hast the max execution time set to 30 sec and we cannot modify it.

One solution would be, to start a php script where I have an iframe that loads the send-php-script with a range from (e.g.) 1-50 users, reload, and then load 51 - 100, and so on

I tried to code it but I failed. here's my attempt:

```
  <script>
<?php
foreach($userids as $id) {
    ?>
    var url = 'cron_send_notify_iframe.php?id= + '<?php echo $id['userid'];?>' + &tabpageid= + '<?php echo $id['tabpageid'];?> ' + &token= + '<?php echo $appAccessToken?>;
    document.getElementById('iframe').src = url;
    <?php
    sleep(1);
}
?>              
</script>
<iframe width="271px" height="295px" frameborder="no" id="iframe" src=""></iframe>
```

cron_send_notify_iframe.php handels just to send of the notification (works fine for an uid).

I thought, that I can send one notification per second. Will that work? Are there better solutions? Maybe give a range ($from - $to) and send them... What do you think?

Comment: _What if_, did it already happen? How long does the script take for 5 uers?

Comment: You should look at Batch Requests instead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/